# GestureDetector: why this code is not working?

Tags: android

Why is this GestureDetector not workink?

I would expect the GestureDetector to be called and detect the double tap

```
@Override
    public void  onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent event) {
                Log.e("onDoubleTap", event.toString());
                //handle double tap
                int x = (int) event.getX();
                int y = (int) event.getY();
                return true;
            }
        });
        gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with this class, but seeing that you are reinitilizing it every time you recieve a touch event I guess that that must be the problem. Try to initialize it in the constructor of your class and the only call `gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);` in this handler

Comment: @Mario Stoilov thanks Mario, it works if I initialize it in the constructor, but since this is a Live Wallpaper I get strange behaviors when I open the Wallpaper in preview... I get  `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Surface has already been released `   :-(((( this is why I am trying to initialize it somewhere else

Comment: try **lazy loading**: in your handler check `if(gestureDetector==null){//initialize it}`

Comment: @Mario Stoilov that did the trick Mario!!! Thanks! Post an answer I will gladly accept and upvote!!!

Comment: @LisaAnne In addition to what Mario said, you probably want to return a boolean from your `onTouchEvent()` method.  Also, I think you want to also override `onDown()` (to return `true`) in your `SimpleOnGestureListener` extension.

Comment: @Mario Stoilov please Mario, if you like, could you explain why this works?  :-)))) Thanks. LISA

Comment: Well I haven't used this class, but I guess in order to recognize a double tap event, it must count the number of times the user has tapped and the interval between the taps. Initializing the class every time voids these counted taps and this way it never could recognize anything.

Comment: @MarioStoilov that makes perfectly sense! Thank you Mario!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are initializing your `gestureDetector` class every time you receive a touch event, preventing it from saving any kind of state, thus it is unable to detect a double tap. You can **lazy load** it instead:

```
@Override
    public void  onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if(gestureDetector == null){
            gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener(){
                @Override
                public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent event) {
                    Log.e("onDoubleTap", event.toString());
                    //handle double tap
                    int x = (int) event.getX();
                    int y = (int) event.getY();
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
        gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong constructor. The Full example of usage the gesture:

```
    private GestureDetectorCompat gesture;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Just the default methods
        gesture = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new OnGestureListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
                    float distanceY) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                    float velocityY) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }
        });

        gesture.setOnDoubleTapListener(new OnDoubleTapListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
                Log.i("GESTURE","DoubleTap");
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        gesture.onTouchEvent(event);
        return true;
    }


}
```